# How do I read properties from ".properties" files in unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

In product code, I can use the following code to read the `aws.default.region` property from
`application.properties` and `application-development.properties`

```
@Value("${aws.default.region:null}")
private String awsDefaultRegion;
```

However, in unit test the same code doesn't work, and `awsDefaultRegion` variable is always null.

I tried to add the following annotation but it doesn't work.

```java
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:application.properties",
        "classpath:application-development.properties"
})
```

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov I am afraid `TestPropertySource` doesn't work either

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? Please, see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is too little information in here. An `@Value` (like `@Autowired`) cannot be `null`. If it is `null` it is because it isn't Spring that is creating an instance but yourself. So you are probably doing `new YourObject()` in your test (or using a Mock) at least something outside the control of Spring. All of this is something we cannot see because you haven't included your actual test class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUnit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test-application.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think inject value on test could be another good way

```java
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(
   serviceMocked, 
  "awsDefaultRegion",  // name attr in service
   valueaTobeInjectWhenTesting
);

// rest of test method
```